Java Primefaces Dependency Managed Bean
I have been suffering and trying many times to create a really simple project with primefaces from tutorials. I have done a lot of them and all of them don't work for me.
They all insert only one dependency:
<dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
           <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
           <version>14.0.1</version>
       </dependency>
</dependencies> 

Even when I inject it I do not have access to those 2 annotations that all tutorials use with only primefaces dependency and they do not mention about any other dependencies.

@ManagedBean
@RequestedScope

Also when I create .xhtml with those namespaces, the last two:
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"

do not work for me. They are displaying this error:
Resource registered by this uri is not recognized (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs)

What am I doing wrong? This is my code:
@ManagedBean
@RequestedScope
public class Beanek {
    public void metoda() {
        System.out.println("Kliknięto przycisk PrimeFaces!");
    }
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>PrimeFaces Example</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:commandButton value="Kliknij mnie" actionListener="#{bean.metoda}" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>doWydupienia</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>20</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>20</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>14.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>19</source>
                    <target>19</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


PrimeFaces in turn depends on JSF which is normally already provided by normal Jakarta EE servers but not by barebones servletcontainers such as Tomcat. See abovelinked duplicate.

You don't need to do any of that PrimeFaces has a simple ready to go out of the box sample project for you. BTW ManagedBean is dead and has been for a long time there is no need for it anymore.  Just use CDI.  Here is PrimeFaces Test project to get you started: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test
Also here is a great BalusC tutorial for getting started with JSF: https://balusc.omnifaces.org/2020/04/jsf-23-tutorial-with-eclipse-maven.html
